# Flight Low-fare Search API not filtering properly by maxPrice

Tags: amadeus

I'm trying to use the endpoint Flight Low-fare Search and I realised that it's not filtering properly by maxPrice.

For example, reaching the next endpoint with maxPrice=100.

https://test.api.amadeus.com/v1/shopping/flight-offers?origin=MAD&destination=BIO&departureDate=2018-12-07&returnDate=2018-12-10&adults=1&maxPrice=100&currency=EUR

I'm getting the following result so I think there is an error:

```
      {
      "price": {
        "total": "185.09",
        "totalTaxes": "39.09"
      },
      "pricePerAdult": {
        "total": "185.09",
        "totalTaxes": "39.09"
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

This bug has been fixed and deployed in production.